# How can reset django apps which migration folder was deleletd?

Tags: django

In my django app path, the migrations folder was deleted, but I want to recover it, when executing migrate command:

python manage.py migrate --fake api.desktops
CommandError: App 'api.desktops' does not have migrations (you cannot selectively sync unmigrated apps)

How can reset those app?

Comment: Why don't you get it back from version control?

Answer (score 1):

If your database and and app are synchronised you should be able to do the following:

```
./manage makemigrations <app_name>
./manage migrate <app_name> --fake
```

If the database is out of sync you can also perform the same as above but will need to manually alter your database to align with the new migration structure.